# Первая ячейка первой строки из результата SQL запроса в PHP 5.6.3

Tags: php

можно, конечно, делать вот так:

```
$result = queryExec($query);
$firstrow = $result -> fetch_assoc();
return $firstrow[$colName];
```

но тогда нам нужно указывать $colName. А это как-то тупо.

В интернете предлагают обращатся к "id", но результатом [0][0] не всегда айдишник, соответственно в таких случаях оно просто бросит ошибку. А лучшего варианта в интернете не нашел.

Итак... В чем секрет доступа к ячейкам по индексу колонки в пхп?

Comment: `fetch_array()` , `$firstrow[0]`

Comment: `В чем секрет доступа к ячейкам по индексу колонки в пхп` - просто есть разные методы получения данных. можно ассоциативный массив, а можно пронумерованный получить. По желанию. Пронумерованный через `fetch_array`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = queryExec($query);
$firstrow = $result -> fetch_array();
return $firstrow[0];
```

или же

`queryExec($query) -> fetch_array()[0];`